# What authentication methods are supported for Cognito Forms connecting to Sharepoint?

Tags: cognito-forms, sharepoint

Trying to connect a Cognito form to a Sharepoint Foundation 2013 list, I get:

> Cannot connect: invalid settings.

The Sharepoint site is using Forms-based authentication with a custom role/membership provider.

I have tried with FBA credentials as well as a Windows Auth account, and neither work.

I also tried changing the URL—using the top-level URL of the site collection as well as the direct URL to the list, plus a few other permutations, and none seemed to work.

Is connecting to a Sharepoint list not supported in this environment? What else would I do to troubleshoot connection problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](http://www.cognitoforms.com) responsible for the SharePoint integration features.

Unfortunately, Cognito Forms does not currently support authentication with SharePoint web applications that utilize forms-based authentication. Supported authentication methods include Windows authentication for on-premises SharePoint web applications and SharePoint Online/Office 365 cloud-based authentication.

After some research, we believe we will be able to add support for multi-authentication SharePoint web applications by adding a custom authentication header to our web service request to force our system to authenticate using Windows authentication - [detailed here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh124553(v=office.14).aspx). This would require your forms-based SharePoint web application to also have Windows Authentication enabled. Is this the case for your web application?

Comment: Yes - my on-premises web application has both forms and windows auth enabled. Any assistance you could provide to get it working in that environment would be appreciated.

Comment: Great. We are actively working on updating our SharePoint integration to support multi-authentication SharePoint sites in a future release of Cognito Forms. 

You can follow our progress on [our idea board](https://trello.com/c/sDCiSoHc). We welcome our users to submit features they would like to see and constantly add and update our idea board with the new features. Our users also have the ability to vote on features they would like to see in the future. This helps give us a guide as to what we should work on in our next and upcoming releases.

Comment: Hi, 

I am pleased to inform you that an update has been released to Cognito Forms to support posting form data to multi-authentication SharePoint sites. To utilize this new feature, please enter a valid Windows username (i.e. domain\username) and password into your Cognito Form's SharePoint submission settings.

Thanks!